# Pointcloud2 vs PointCloud2Ptr

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, pcl, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, the message i am subscribing to from a topic is PointCloud2, whereas my subscriber callback routine looks like this

```
void cloud_callback (const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& cloud_msg){
 ROS_INFO("inside callback");
}

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
 ros::init (argc, argv, "cloud_sub");
 ros::NodeHandle nh;
 ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
 ros::Subscriber sub;
 while (nh.ok()) {
   sub = nh.subscribe ("input_cloud", 1, cloud_callback);
   ros::spinOnce ();
   loop_rate.sleep ();
 }
}
```

Will the fact that the callback type is a Ptr affect the message? How should i take in a Ptr in my callback with the fact that my message subscribed to is PointCloud2 datatype?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380694/pointcloud2-vs-pointcloud2ptr/) by [gyrados10](https://answers.ros.org/users/75016/gyrados10/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The PointCloud2Ptr is just a pointer to your PointCloud2 datatype. The actual sensor data is held in the PointCloud2 message structure and a pointer is passed to the callback to prevent duplication of data (saving time and memory) and other benefits that CS majors can fill you in.

You can still access your data in your callback using the `->` operator. For eg: `cloud_msg->size()`

---

Originally posted by [Akhil Kurup](https://answers.ros.org/users/63962/akhil-kurup/) with karma: 459 on 2021-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gyrados10](https://answers.ros.org/users/75016/gyrados10/) on 2021-06-21**:
yeah, but do you mean that the callback will automatically convert my subscribed msg from raw data form to a pointer form?

**Comment by [Akhil Kurup](https://answers.ros.org/users/63962/akhil-kurup/) on 2021-06-21**:
There is no need to convert anything. The pointer is just a symbolic reference to the address where the sensor data is stored.